# Why does my car engine rev so fast when running uphill

Tags: engine, maintenance

I have a 2015 Civic EX (6000 miles). It's revving 2000/2500/3000RPM at 70/80/90MPH on flat ground. However, it's having 3000RPM at 60MPH when going uphill and EVERYONE was passing me by (Except for the trucks).

Since the engine is making noisy sound at 3000RPM already, is it good for my car to go over 3000RPM if I want it to last longer?

Comment: Is it a manual or automatic transmission?

Comment: It's CVT automatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely your Honda has a [CVT transmission](http://www.autotrader.com/car-info/definitions-continuously-variable-transmission-cvt-211130) and this is normal behavior for a computer controlled CVT, to let it rev higher when under a load such as driving up a hill.

Comment: I didn't take into account CVT with my answer, so I deleted it ... was asleep at the wheel. The whole idea of the CVT is to keep the engine in its torque band. How would the fact the OP is being passed *by everyone* fit into the "is normal behavior" narrative? Could it be the OP isn't pushing the vehicle hard enough?

Comment: Should I push it over 3000RPM? Will that do any harm to my car?

Comment: Small engines like those used in compact cars will happily rev and often need to in order to maintain their power band - one of the reasons CVTs fit them so well. Just worry about what speed you're trying to maintain and let the car's computer decide what RPMs are appropriate.

Comment: I would think up to 4200 rpm would be totally normal in certain conditions and for a short period of time.   I wouldn't expect any harm to engine in those conditions. What's redline on your tachometer 5500 or 6000 rpm?  Redline = can cause damage to engine.  Whoa. Redline on Civics is 8000 rpm?

Comment: Sounds about right, redline on my 94 Integra with the 1.8L VTEC is 8k.  Those little suckers rev high.  Only gets 20mph/1000 RPM in top gear, I'm sitting about 3000 RPM doing 60mph.  I've driven it a couple hundred miles maintaining about 4000 RPM for hours at a time.  Engine has 350K miles on it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 more than likely it has a small engine or is afraid to flatten the gas pedal to the floor.

Comment: Redline varies, of course. For performance VTEC engines, 8000 rpm sounds about right. My Accord 1.8 VTEC-e redlined at 6200.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - let the car go over 3000rpm . The honda is happy to rev right to the redline....